# C# MongoDB and update list of items

Tags: c#, mongodb, collections, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a list of objects which are decorated with MongoCollection attribute.

I want to save it all at once. Now I have something like this in a loop:

```
public virtual void Save(TEntity item, Context context)
    {
        var filter = Builders<TEntity>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, item.Id);
        GetCollection(context).ReplaceOne(filter, item, new UpdateOptions
        {
            IsUpsert = true
        });
    }
```

How can I archive this?

Comment: If you're looking for one atomic operation to do that, you might not find any. As technically that might end up in a situation where in middle of the update/replace process your database has crashed and the database state would end up in a position where some of the items has been replaced and some of them hasn't

Answer (score -1):

There is `updateMany` [method](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateManyModel_1.htm) in mongodb c# driver.
Also if you would like to insert the set of documents you can use `insertMany` method.